# Switch bottom clicked event in menu toolbar

Tags: java, android

i want to add switch button in toolbar. so i made thislayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/filter"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"/>

    <com.kyleduo.switchbutton.SwitchButton
        android:id="@+id/sb_ios"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:kswAnimationDuration="300"
        app:kswBackDrawable="@drawable/ios_back_drawable"
        app:kswBackMeasureRatio="1.4"
        app:kswThumbDrawable="@drawable/ios_thumb_selector"
        app:kswThumbMarginBottom="-8dp"
        app:kswThumbMarginLeft="-5dp"
        app:kswThumbMarginRight="-5dp"
        app:kswThumbMarginTop="-2.5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    android:title="Open Filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

and in fragment

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cvs_fav, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.switch_button_toolbar);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.i("Whatt", "enter");
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.myswitch) {
        Log.i("Whatt", "enter1");
        if (bSwitch) {
            Log.i("Whatt", "enter2");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bSwitch = false;
        } else {
            Log.i("Whatt", "enter3");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bSwitch = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but the problem here the **setOnMenuItemClickListener** not working in item and when try **onOptionsItemSelected** not enter in function which **log.i()** not showing anything also although on menu item is add
please help !!

Comment: Have you invoked `setHasOptionsMenu(true); ` in `onCreate` method of your fragment? Also Im not 100% sure, but I think there is no need to call `menu.clear();`. And no need to do both - override `onOptionsItemSelected` and `setOnMenuItemClickListener`

Comment: yea i add in onCreate method

Comment: i know but i do for just test